# Using QtMultimediaKit in PyQt

Tags: pyqt

I am a little confused here.

Can I use QtMultimediaKit in PyQt to make a Video Player in a Desktop Application or is it specifically for Mobiles?

Also, is there an example of QtMultimedia being used to Load a video file, and playing it?

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation on the [PyQt website](http://www.riverbankcomputing.com), QtMultimediaKit is part of [PyQtMobility](http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqtmobility/intro), which provides Python bindings for Nokia's QtMobility libraries (i.e. it's for mobile devices).

With regard to QtMultimedia, you should note in particular:

> The QtMultimediaKit module provides support for audio, video and radio based applications. It is the replacement for the **deprecated QtMultimedia module** in PyQt.

Given this, and that QtMultimedia only provides *low-level* functionality, it's very unlikely that there is much (or any) existing PyQt code that uses it.

If you want alternatives to [Phonon](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/phonon-overview.html), you should try the [Python GStreamer bindings](http://pygstdocs.berlios.de/).